# Ruby: Custom gem demands a 'require' for module therein

Tags: ruby, module, rubygems, require

I've built a custom Ruby gem. Call it `MyGem`, then file `lib/innermodule.rb` contains:

```
module MyGem
    module InnerModule
        def self.foo(); puts "Hello world!"; end
    end
end
```

To reference this from another gem that's in development I have to do:

```
require 'mygem'
require 'innermodule'
```

Is this normal behaviour, or is there a problem with the gemspec for `MyGem`?

Comment: require 'InnerModule' is weird if there isn't a file called InnerModule.rb (or .so, .bundle etc. for native extensions)

Comment: Thank you for spotting that Frederick, it was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: sounds like a problem with your gemspec - you should not need to reference an internal dependency

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this is necessarily a problem with your gemspec since you usually just specify what files to include in a gem. Gemspecs don't really have anything to do with the way a gem gets required into another app.

It sounds like a problem with the way your gem is built/packaged specifically with regards to naming and file path conventions.

There are some common conventions that are usually followed for building gems and what I referenced above

http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/ has a good overview.

Basically, you usually want to create a single file (usually the name of your gem) that sits in the "lib" directory. In this case, "lib/mygem.rb" would have individual requires for the internal dependencies of the gem.

```
#lib/mygem.rb
require 'innermodule'
```

Then to include the gem (as well as the inner module) in any other app, you could just do

```
require 'mygem'
```

Comment: Thank you for this info. My confusion stemmed from assuming `require 'gem-name'` was needed after seeing examples. However gems are inherently included, so instead you `require 'class-from-gem'` to require a class from any gem required by yours and `require 'dir-name/class'` may simply look like it contains the gem name if the gem's `lib/` directory contains a directory `gem-name`. As you've said above, the fix for my gem as it stands is simply to `require 'innermodule'` to pull in `innermodule.rb` from the already-imported gem, then reference in code as `MyGem::InnerModule`.

Comment: Sorry, you may not have seen my edit. The easiest way to go about this is to just have your 'mygem.rb' file require any internal dependencies that it needs to run. This is more of a 'one and done' type of thinking. So for instance, once you've required 'mygem' in your app, you can simply 'include MyGem::InnerModule' in any of the classes that you want within the app that required 'mygem'

Comment: I did see your edit, don't worry. Thank you for explaining anyway. I understand what you're saying, but in my case `InnerModule` is actually something for outside use only - I just chose a rather poor surrogate name for it here :)